# Include in match if pattern exist

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to match numbers like this:

```
-0015.22  => -15.22
 012      =>  12
-5        => -5
 0150-12  =>  150, -12
```

I currently have:

```
-?0*(\d+\.?\d*)
```

Which works for all cases, the issue is that when there is a "-" in the beginning it is not included in the capture (obviously, since it is not enclosed).

How do i include the "-?" in the capture group to the right, while still ignoring the 0's?

Comment: Just match the numbers with the minus and zeros, and as a post-process, use `s.sub(/\A(-?)0+/, '\1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will have to be some post-processing, but a simpler approach (well, at least for me that is) would be something like the following using the regex of `(-?)0*(\d\.?\d*)`:

```
regex = /(-?)0*(\d\.?\d*)/

results = []
[
    "-0015.22",
    "012",
    "-5",
    "0150-12"
].each { |s|
    result = s.scan( regex )
    result.each { |r|
        results << r.join("")
    }
}

puts "results: #{results}"
```

Can see the live sample [here](http://ideone.com/DzMPZS)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not possible to match and put non-adjoining texts into 1 single capture, you may use a work-around: match the numbers and then remove the leading zeros as a post-processing step:

```
s = '-0015.22   012   -5  0150-12'
res = s.scan(/-?0*\d+(?:\.\d*)?/).map { |item|
    item.sub(/\A(-?)0+/, '\1')
}
# res = ["-0015.22", "012", "-5", "0150", "-12"]
```

See the [online Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/WIm14q).

Here, `.sub(/\A(-?)0+/, '\1')` will remove all 1+ zeros at the beginning of a string (`\A`) while preserving the optional `-` that is captured 1 or 0 times (with `(-?)`) and then inserted into the result using a backreference `\1`.